# Group by dataframe with custom weeks based on days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that has 3 time columns and columns for year, month and day. Below is an example of what the first rows of this dataframe looks like, the original starts on the last day of August 2021 and ends in May 2023.
I need to make a groupby but not with the month or days, but with weeks that generally start on tuesdays. For example, week 1 would be from the 31st of the month 08 of 22 to the 5th of the month 09 of 22, the following week starts on the 6th of the month 09 of 22 to the 12th of the month 09 of 22, and so on.

| Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 | Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.980445097064001 | 0.517783564814815 | 0.653634259259259 | 22 | 08 | 31 |
| 0.039616078330327 | 0.030064935790686 | 0.030084640719623 | 22 | 09 | 1 |
| 0.029309456325689 | 0.089149799380819 | 0.047583843892765 | 22 | 09 | 2 |
| 0.304246650347848 | 0.192566472567143 | 0.234001487410136 | 22 | 09 | 3 |
| 0.019944923988663 | 0.93130888647972 | 0.529907568084428 | 22 | 09 | 4 |
| 0.626827814996135 | 0.688218792261353 | 0.688330027977476 | 22 | 09 | 5 |
| 0.678619791666667 | 0.518741319444444 | 0.685700231481482 | 22 | 09 | 6 |
| 0.029296766738725 | 0.005354841948493 | 0.002515001392534 | 22 | 09 | 7 |
| 0.081336795562207 | 0.051813673812034 | 0.018997544075821 | 22 | 09 | 8 |
| 0.167960738665677 | 0.752662081583248 | 0.9080547561377 | 22 | 09 | 9 |
| 0.473579185694002 | 0.927743101457521 | 0.458363223590375 | 22 | 09 | 10 |
| 0.72140569903339 | 0.190169402656225 | 0.070432698393944 | 22 | 09 | 11 |

The following is more or less what I want, which is to group the dataframe based on those weeks and add up the times of each day.  Any idea?

| Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 | Year | Month | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sum | sum | sum | 22 | 08 | 31 - 5 |
| sum | sum | sum | 22 | 09 | 6-12 |
| sum | sum | sum | 22 | 09 | 13-19 |
| sum | sum | sum | 22 | 09 | 20-26 |
| sum | sum | sum | 22 | 10 | 27-3 |

Comment: "week 1 would be from the 31st of the month 08 of 22 to the 5th of the month 09 of 22". This is only 6 days. And also 31/08/2022 was a Wednesday, not Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output, it looks like you want the aggregation to occur from Tuesday-Monday. You can use `resample`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"].add(2000).astype(str)+df["Month"].astype(str)+df["Day"].astype(str),format="%Y%m%d")
output = df.resample(on="date", rule="W-MON").agg({"Time 1": "sum", 
                                                   "Time 2": "sum", 
                                                   "Time 3": "sum", 
                                                   "Year": "first", 
                                                   "Month": "first",
                                                   "Day": "first",
                                                   })

output["Week"] = output["Day"].astype(str)+"-"+output.index.day.astype(str)
output = output.drop(columns="Day").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
     Time 1    Time 2    Time 3  Year  Month  Week
0  2.000390  2.449092  2.183542    22      8  31-5
1  2.152199  2.446484  2.144063    22      9  6-12
```

Comment: I don't see you used resample, I think part of the code is missing.

Comment: @Alejandra - Apologies, was trying to add the week column. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the number of days the start of your first week and round down the number of weeks to get the week number and use that column as your groupby.

```
df['Year'] += 2000
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
df['Delta_Days'] = df['Date'] - np.datetime64('2022-08-31', 'D')
df['Delta_Weeks'] = (df['Delta_Days']/np.timedelta64(7, 'D')).astype(int)
df.groupby('Delta_Weeks')
```